# What is the difference between coloring a model with materials vs textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, color

I'm watching tutorials and I noticed that they always use textures and uv to color the models, but I like using materials to color them, is that wrong?

P.S. I only do low poly models

Comment: textures are part of materials, you mean you prefer using materials without textures, aka procedural textures? I think every one has his preferences regarding this topic, a good exercise is always to first try to make it procedurally, and if it's too hard or not doable, use textures

Comment: I meant coloring it by using the base color in the material preferences

Comment: I think most of these models are created to be reused in other software such as game engines. You can export materials based on uv maps (=PBR workflow) but you can't export procedural materials so it's easier in the end to use uvs to color the models. Also if you use one material per different color, this can lead to your file bloating when you add multiple objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Texture

Textures give you the pattern. This can be an image or a computer generated pattern. It can have colors or it can be black/white. It just simple pattern without any additional information. It doesn't know how rough the surface is. It doesn't know if it's metallic or not. It doesn't know if it emits light or lets it pass through. Just plain picture. In node editor you can manipulate textures with converter nodes and they output different texture.

[image: Texture 1]

[image: Texture 2]

### Material

Material is what you get when you combine all the properties that the surface has. Material can have textures in it. The pattern is still there but there are so much more. There is the pattern but also in the pattern there are bumps that reflect light. There are areas that are metal. There are areas that are see through and there are areas that are mirror like.

[image: Material]

[image: Materials]

Before Principled BSDF shader you had to use multiple shaders to create your material. Now you can do quite well with just a single shader. You can think of Principled BSDF as a combination of multiple shaders. Basically you have textures and you feed them into shaders. In some cases your textures may just be black or white (0 or 1) if you want the whole material to be uniform. For example the whole material might be metallic and the metallic value would be 1 everywhere.

You then combine your shaders and feed them into material output. This is the material that you have.

If you don't use textures then your material has the same property everywhere. If you want to have different properties at different parts of your material then you have to use textures.

Comment: thanks a lot, I understand now

Comment: From the way your present this, it seems like Textures is subsumed in Materials, or is a simpler subset of Materials.  Is that a fair interpretation?